# pyspark Join multiple Dataframes

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am new in the spark and big data world.
I transferred my MySQL database to HDFS with some airflow DAGs and now every table is a parquet file in HDFS now I need to convert blew query to pyspark over dataframes.

```sql
SELECT PV.id product_id,
       ZP.vendor_id vendor_id,
       V.title vendor_name,
       PV.barcode barcode,
       PV.title product_title,
       ZP.active product_active,
       ZP.price product_price,
       ZP.capacity product_capacity,
       ZP.stock product_stock,
       MC1.title subcat_title,
       MC2.title parent_category_title,
       ZB.title brand_name
FROM xpediaProductVariationVendorInfo ZP
JOIN ProductVariations PV ON PV.id = ZP.xpediaProductVariation_id
JOIN Vendors V ON ZP.vendor_id = V.id
JOIN VendorTypes vt ON V.vendor_type_id = vt.id
JOIN xpediaProductVariation ZPV ON ZPV.id = PV.id
JOIN MenuCategories MC1 ON PV.menu_category_id = MC1.id
LEFT JOIN MenuCategories MC2 ON MC1.parent_id = MC2.id
LEFT JOIN xpedia_brand ZB ON ZB.id = ZPV.brand_id
WHERE ZP.vendor_id={}
  AND V.status not in ('Suspend')
GROUP BY PV.id,
         ZP.vendor_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is alot of logic there and your group by doesnt fall in line with your selected columns. (12 columns selected and only 2 grouped)
In pyspark you will have to rewrite something like below -

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_output = (df_xpediaProductVariationVendorInfo.alias("ZP")
             .join (df_ProductVariations.alias("PV"), F.col("PV.id") == F.col("ZP.xpediaProductVariation_id"))
             .join (df_Vendors.alias("V"), F.col("ZP.vendor_id") == F.col("V.id"))
             .join (df_VendorTypes.alias("vt"), F.col("V.vendor_type_id") == F.col("vt.id"))
             .join (df_xpediaProductVariation.alias("ZPV"), F.col("ZPV.id") == F.col("PV.id"))
             .join (df_MenuCategories.alias("MC1"), F.col("PV.menu_category_id") = F.col("MC1.id"))
             .join (df_MenuCategories.alias("MC2"), F.col("MC1.parent_id") = F.col("MC2.id"), "left")
             .join (df_xpedia_brand.alias("ZB"), F.col("ZB.id") = F.col("ZPV.brand_id"), "left")
             .where ((F.col("ZP.vendor_id") == {}) 
                     & ~(F.col("V.status").isin('Suspend')))
             .select(F.col("PV.id"),
                     F.col("ZP.vendor_id"),
                     F.col("V.title"),
                     F.col("PV.barcode"),
                     F.col("PV.title"),
                     F.col("ZP.active"),
                     F.col("ZP.price"),
                     F.col("ZP.capacity"),
                     F.col("ZP.stock"),
                     F.col("MC1.title"),
                     F.col("MC2.title"),
                     F.col("ZB.title"))
            )

df_output.show()
```